# Proper way to add index columns in greenDao?

Tags: android, orm, greendao

I am building a data model in greenDAO. It is a port of an iOS app that uses Core Data. In iOS we use indexes (indices?) to increase lookup performance in a table of 20 columns (properties) where 5 columns are frequently queried. I know this results in extra storage and provides slower writes into the table.

Digging in the documentation, I came across the addIndex(Index index) method in [Entity](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao-generator/index.html?de/greenrobot/daogenerator/Entity.html) and the index() method in [Property.PropertyBuilder](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao-generator/de/greenrobot/daogenerator/Property.PropertyBuilder.html). Which is the correct way to add an index to an Entity?

```
Entity entity = schema.addEntity("entity");
entity.setSuperclass("SuperClass");
entity.addIdProperty();
entity.addIntProperty("property").index();
```

or

```
Entity entity = schema.addEntity("entity");
entity.setSuperclass("SuperClass");
entity.addIdProperty();
Property property = entity.addIntProperty("property").getProperty();
entity.setIndex(property);
```

Or do they both do the same thing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use **myProperty.index()** for single property indexes (because it is most convenient).

For more complex indexes, like multi-column indexes, use addIndex(index):

```
Index index = new Index();
index.addProperty(property1);
index.addProperty(property2);
entity.addIndex(index);
```

Comment: Isn't here should be index.makeUnique(); ?

Comment: @Flinbor `makeUnique()` is optional. Use it to prevent two rows of having the same values in both columns.

Comment: maybe this is outdated, but when I try it throws an error saying `Index` is abstract so I cannot instantiate it...