# GreenDAO - primary key on multiple columns

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key, greendao

Does GreenDAO support primary key on multiple columns?

I'm using `Property`'s method `primaryKey()` on two columns but it doesn't work. I'm getting exception:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table "table" has
>   more than one primary key

How to create primary key on multiple columns? Should I edit generated DAO classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/modelling-entities/) says:

> Currently, entities must have a long or Long property as their primary key.
>   [...]
>   To work around this issue, you can use a long primary key and use an unique index for the intended “key” properties.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147011/proper-way-to-add-index-columns-in-greendao

Comment: and autoincrement?

Comment: @Skynet Autoincrement does not work with multiple columns to begin with. This would be a different question.